"At the time they plan to go"
Following is an excerpt from a question from the GMAT. ­

The couple decide one day that they will definitely go to the beach the next evening if it is sunny without rain at the time they plan to go—and that they will definitely not go if such is not the case. The next morning, the hour-by-hour weather forecast says that in the evening, it will be sunny without rain. Will the couple go to the beach that evening?

While reading this, I mistakenly understood “at the time they plan to go” as “at the time they make the plan,” not the actual time they planned to visit the beach, which the question intended. Can anyone explain how to avoid such a misinterpretation?

The context makes that amply clear, doesn't it? And why should weather make a difference at all if, according to you, at the time they plan to go meant at the time they made the plan? There's a grammatical reason as well: the  bolded adverb phrase should have followed the verb decide if it meant what you thought.

Grammatically you could interpret it as there being a separate, third time at which they habitually plan beach trips (separate from making the decision to go on a trip - you can even plan a trip hypothetically before you decide to go on it), and if it's sunny at that time, then they'll go to the beach. But that would be insane.

After reading your comments, would it make sense grammatically? In "at the time they plan to go," "at the time" modifies "go." If it were to mean the time they make the plan, it would be "at the time they plan," so that "at the time" can modify the verb "plan."

The GMAT intends/plans on this ambiguity. I tutor this exam and can say the trap here is that the final question of go ... that evening? is not answered by weather reports in the morning, but only when they travel there. The evening is "when they plan to go." The best answer will say "Cannot be determined from the passage," since it cannot be determined yet. And sunny without rain is bad English and logic.

Given that this a GMAT question, the wording is tortured and intended to confuse and mislead. The best approach, typically, is to read such passages quite literally and apply the rules of grammar and usage rigorously despite the woefully inadequate style used. As others have noted, "at the time they plan to go" specifies the time they would leave on their outing, weather permitting at that time. It's confusing because it's both subjunctive, i.e., the time they would leave, and determinative, i.e., the time they will decide whether to go.
"At the time" is an intentionally wordy substitute for "when." That may help make the meaning clearer. From its position in the sentence, following "the next evening" and before the option they will pursue, "at the time they plan to go" clearly means the time when they would leave on their journey. Further, for the phrase to have a different meaning or refer to a different period, "at the time" has to refer to a different phrase from "they plan to go," which idiomatically means "when they would depart." For instance, "at the time they make the plan to go" would change the meaning to "when they make the plan" rather than when they would leave.
Obviously, though not especially clearly, a forecast for later in the day is not the same as checking the weather at the time you are departing, so we have not idea whether they departed on their journey.
This is pretty typical GMAT writing—overwordy, using bizarre phrasing that it still technically standard English, and mixing the past, present, and future to distract one from focusing on the specific question at hand. One must recognize that the decision will be made at the time they would leave, not earlier or later. So information that occurs at any time other than when they would leave is irrelevant.

The cited text is inherently confusing because these three verb tenses are conflicting...

...they (1) will go ... if it (2) is sunny [when] they (3) plan to go

Morphologically, (2) and (3) both use Present tense, but semantically, (2) refers to the same future time as (1), whereas (3) refers to some imprecisely-identified earlier time.
To explicitly convey that (3) refers to an earlier time...

...they (1) will go ... if it (2) is sunny [when] they (3) [have] planned to go

Note that in the spoken version, if have isn't present, most native speakers would be unable to articulate and/or hear the difference between plan and planned when followed by to.
Also note that in principle, the earlier time of (3) could even be before the current "narrative reference time" of the sentence (the time when they decide to make this plan). You might perhaps be able to convey that with ...when they had planned to go or ...when they had been planning to go, but I certainly wouldn't want to rely on that being understood.
If the precise interpretation had real significance (in the context of legal proceedings, say) it would need a complete rewrite to resolve potential ambiguity.


The couple decide one day that they will definitely go to the beach the next evening if it is sunny without rain at the time they plan to go—and that they will definitely not go if such is not the case.

Since they decided on a particular day to go to the beach the next evening, it is evident that they already made a definite plan for this event to take place the next day, weather permitting; could they be willing to  go to the beach still if at the very time they reach the beach, the weather is sunny, while in an hour's time after that it starts to rain or vice-versa? Anyway, is there the possibility of a weather forecast that could precisely tell the time of one or more showers during an evening? No. In consequence, this second "planning" seems very unlikely: for this sort of outing people want the weather to remain nice throughout, and in any case they know that they can't rely on weather forecasts of ultimate accuracy. It seems that the sentence can be made to match that context easily then.

The couple decide one day that they will definitely go to the beach the next evening if it is sunny, that is,  without any chance of an occasional shower—and that they will definitely not go if such is not the case.

If it is still needed to stick to the exact context of the sentence, then an unambiguous formulation can be obtained by means of  some small modification: making the word "time" the object of "plan" through the use of a relative pronoun shows unmistakably the wanted relation between the terms.

The couple decide one day that they will definitely go to the beach the next evening if the time that they plan for their outing is sunny without rain—and that they will definitely not go if such is not the case.



if it is sunny without rain at the time they plan to go -- Can anyone explain how to avoid such a misinterpretation?

The verb "plan" is at fault. It should be "intend".
